# How to use https(ssl) in c#+npgsql application?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I have a Winforms app using npgsql provider.
It seems it uses unencrypted plain text queries.
How to use encrypted queries to PostgreSQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SSL/TLS when using Npgsql to connect to PostgreSQL, [see the docs](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/security.html).

Note - HTTPS isn't involved here in any way. The PostgreSQL protocol is a binary wire protocol which isn't based on HTTP.

Comment: Thanx! Shay, what certificate is better (easier) to use if I use PostgreSQL Server in AWS?

Comment: Ok, yet another question: how to run openssl on Windows? ie. how to generate certificate on windows?

Comment: Search around the web, there are quite a few tutorials on that, including specifically for setting things up with PostgreSQL.